# Call to a member function xx() on a non-object (which is an object actually)

Tags: symfony

ValidateGatherType.php

```
namespace D2E\CoreBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

class ValidateGatherType extends AbstractType
{
    private $gather;

    public function __construct(Gather $gather) 
    {
        $this->gather = $gather;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $gather_players = $gather->getGatherPlayers();
    }
```

}

GatherController.php

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
class GatherController extends Controller
{

/**
 * @Route("/teams/{id_team}/gather/{id_gather}")
 * @Template()
 */
public function showAction(Team $team, Gather $gather) 
{
    new ValidateGatherType($gather);
}
```

Error I got when doing this $gather->getGatherPlayers():

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getGatherPlayers() on a non-object
```

Soooooo, wtf(it is forced as Gather but then it's not an object anymore?)? I think I forgot an use or something but I can't find what.
The controller code is different but since that line is not working (even if I use it like I show you) I didn't put the rest of the code.

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $gather_players = $gather->getGatherPlayers();
}
```

The local variable `$gather` is not defined here. You propably mean the instance property `$this->gather`